# OpenGL Matrix Stack

Tags: opengl, matrix, stack

If I call

```
float before[16];
float during[16];
float after[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, before);
glPushMatrix();
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, during);
glPopMatrix();
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, after);
```

The values of before and after are different. Did I miss something, I had thought that None of these functions should even modify the Matrix. It would appear that Pop is the culprit, as during is equal to before.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. What are the values of before/after? Do you recognize them? My only other thought it to check glGetError in case something else has gone wrong.

Comment: Actually the values for all 3 retrieved matrices should be identical with this code. Anyway, the matrix stack has been deprecated and entirely removed from OpenGL-3 and later.

Comment: "The values of before and after are different." How "different" are they? Are you doing a `==` test on them, or are you doing a proper floating-point equality test?

Comment: @Tim I think there is an error, I get 1283
Stack overflow...

Awkward.... <.<   >.>

Sorry for wasting yall's time

Answer (score 0):

They *should* be the same. glPushMatrix pushes a copy of the current matrix, after that, the previous shouldn't be affected, and will become current again after glPopMatrix.

Check glGetError. If the matrix stack overflows, something bad might happen.